# The PayPal REST API doesn't allow credit cards to be deleted?

Tags: api, security, paypal, e-commerce, privacy

The PayPal REST API [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/) shows how to store a credit card and how to use a stored credit card, but I don't see anything about deleting a stored credit card. Of course, I can simply delete the card ID from my database, but I feel like this is slightly misleading to the customer, who may not realize that their information will be stored *indefinitely* on PayPal's servers. How is this typically handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David, you currently can't delete a stored credit card. However, stay tuned for some credit card storage updates that are coming soon.

Comment: Are you a PayPal employee?

Comment: Soon as in a few days, or soon as in soon(tm)? http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=soon%20(tm)

Comment: @David soon as in live in production now and documented shortly. :) And yes, both Jatin and I are PayPal employees.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks guys! This really helped us in making a few important decisions about our application.

Comment: @David sorry, I was misinformed. It's not in production, it's approved for production. It'll be live within a couple of weeks, though. So genuinely soon, not soon(tm). Sorry again.

Comment: @David Just wanted to follow up with you and let you know that the ability to delete stored credit cards is now live: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#delete-a-stored-credit-card